# need to create pure CSS3 Shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image]

I need to create above shape with pure css3.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yurzui/5nt8vj0r/

Comment: thanks..I have tried another method... https://jsfiddle.net/arunkrishnans/ar75tdzk/4/